# Return the current object (*this) in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code:

Code 1

```
class Student {
     int no;
     char grade[M+1];
 public:
     Student() {
         no = 0;
         grade[0] = '\0';
     }
     void set(int n, const char* g) {
         no = n;
         strcpy(grade, g);

     }
     const Student getObject() {
         return *this;
     }
     void display() const {
         cout << no << ", " << grade << endl;
     }
 };
```

Code 2:

```
// no change from code 1
const Student& getObject() {
         return *this;
     }
// no change from code 1
```

As the book I am reading explains the difference in the getObject() of the code 1 and 2 is that the getObject() of code 2 returns a reference to the current object, instead of a copy (for efficiency reasons).

However, I have tested (code 2) as follows:

Tested code:

```
Student harry, harry1;
    harry.set(123, "ABCD");

    harry1 = harry.getObject();
    harry1.set(1111,"MMMMMM");
    harry.display(); // Line 1 => displayed: 123, ABCD
    harry1.display(); / Line 2 => displayed: 1111, MMMMMM
```

I dont get it. If the getObject() returns a reference, then Line 1 in the tested code should also display 111, MMMMMM? Because I thought that harry1 should contain the address of harry object???
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's not just for efficiency. Sometimes a copy may not be possible.

Comment: re all suggestions to modify `harry1` to be `Student&` - this will not work as `getObj()` returns a **const** ref to Student, so this would not compile.

Comment: Read about assignment operator. You are using it like this `harry1 = harry.getObject();`. It copies one object's value to another object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `harry.getObject()` is a reference to the original object, you then ruin it with the assignment:

```
harry1 = harry.getObject();
```

which performs a copy.

Instead:

```
Student const& harry1 = harry.getObject();
```

Comment: Won't compile. :) `const` reference is returned. So `const Student& harry1 = harry.getObject();` must be used.

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning the reference returned by `getObject` to a `Student`, so it gets copied just a few steps later as in Code 1 (where it would be copied directly upon returning from `getObject`). Use

```
Student& harry1 = harry.GetObject();
```

to obtain a reference to harry. Note that you must declare and initialize references in one step.

Answer (score 2):

You are using actual objects, not pointers or references. When you say:

```
harry1 = harry.getObject()
```

the contents of harry are copied by the default assignment operator into harry1.

Answer (score 1):

harry1 in your test code is an instance of Student, not a reference. Change it to this:

```
Student harry;
harry.set(123, "ABCD");

Student& harry1 = harry.getObject();
harry1.set(1111,"MMMMMM");
harry.display(); // Line 1 => displayed: 123, ABCD
harry1.display(); / Line 2 => displayed: 1111, MMMMMM
```

Answer (score 1):

Common advise : define a copy constructor, private and not implemented:

```
private:
  Student(Student& xOther);
```

This way, if you happen to have unwanted copy, compiler will detect them (your harry1 is actually a copy). And if you expect to have copies, you can properly control how they are done, thus avoiding to mess with potential pointers or encapsulated objects.